# prevent cocoa application from becoming active

Tags: macos, cocoa, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I have a cocoa application that has an NSView in the primary NSWindow that can be clicked. When the NSView is clicked, I want the mousedown event to fire, but I do not want my application to become the active application.

For example, if the user is in Safari typing in a webpage and clicks my application's button with the mouse, then they should still be in Safari's webpage able to type without any further action.

Comment: I am looking into a solution using NSWorkspace to get the active application before my app with FrontmostApplication, and storing that app reference. Then I can allow whatever logic I need to happen within my app, and will call Activate for the app which I have reference to. This should accomplish what I want, but I don't know if this is the best way.

Comment: How would a button become clicked in your application without it becoming active? If it wasn't active you wouldn't be able to click it's button.

Comment: To accept the mouseDown: without activating your window, you need to override `-acceptsFirstMouse:` and return `YES`. To prevent the application from becoming active you can make the whole application a "background" app by setting `NSApplication.activationPolicy` to `NSApplicationActivationPolicyProhibited`. I'm not aware of a way to do this on a per-event basis.

Comment: @l'L'l You can have controls be able to be interacted with on first click, even if your app is not the active app. This is possible with the AcceptsFirstMouse property override on the control.

Comment: @JamesBucanek Thank you, I will look into the activationPolicy as an alternative to my current solution which is to capture the active app just before mine becomes active, performing any logic I need to, and then setting the previous app to be active. I can elaborate on my current solution as an answer if no one has a better idea.