# How to make sure that dragging into my app's window doesn't cause the other app's window to lose focus?

Tags: swift, appkit

I am working on a MacOS app using Swift/Appkit. I have an NSPanel that is always visible and is a dock replacement. It can receive a drag and drop from any other app, but I don't want it to become the key window and get focus when something is dragged into it. I tried setting canBecomeKey as follows:

```
override var canBecomeKey: Bool { false }
```

And this is making sure the window doesn't get focus either when clicked, or when something is dragged into it. But when the mouse is dragged into it, then hovered for a bit, the other app's window from which the drag started is losing focus. Is there any way that I stop this from happening? I don't want the other app's window to lose focus.

Comment: Does your app have other windows? Which app is the active app?

Comment: @Willeke Only this window. And one instance of: class App: NSApplication, NSApplicationDelegate

Comment: Which window should be key window when the panel isn't? Which app is the active frontmost app, your app or the other dragging source app?

Comment: @Willeke My bad. I didn't make it clear. Check out the updated question. Thanks

Comment: But which app is the active, frontmost app (and owns the menu bar)? Can your app be the frontmost app? Is your app becoming the frontmost app the problem?

Comment: @Willeke after some more investigation, I realized that my app's window is not getting focus (and I confirm that with the menu bar). So the only issue actually is that other apps are losing focus when I drag something from them to my app's window. I will update the question

Comment: What are `styleMask` of the panel and `activationPolicy` of the app?

Comment: stylemask of the panel is nonactivatingPanel and activationPolicy is not set, so it should be the default

Comment: setting the activation policy to prohibited actually solved my problem :) thanks. feel free to add an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: I got the idea from [prevent cocoa application from becoming active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48993538/prevent-cocoa-application-from-becoming-active)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will post it as an answer for other people, as the comments aren't always read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `styleMask` of the app's panel or window to `.nonactivatingPanel`, and the `NSApplication`'s `activationPolicy` to `.prohibited`